# I want to delete all the data in my tables that contain a subscription column

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to delete all the data on my database tables that contain a `subscription` or `subscription_id` column.

**subscription** or **subscription_id** column is PK or FK.

I have 7 tables that contains `subscription_id` column and 78 tables that contains `subscription` column.

Is it possible to do that in sql query?

Comment: Do you use Foreign Key constraints? And what's your DataBase engine? *MySQL*, *MSSQL*, etc?

Comment: yes sir were using Foreign Key constraints.

Comment: Depending on the environment, you could disable your constraints and delete from all those tables, then enable them again. Otherwise you'll have to work up from the lowest levels, which is something only you can write without a fault, since that would require insight in the actual DB structure.

Comment: Simply write 7 + 78 = 85 delete statements! (Seems like a very poor db design.)

Comment: @Jens Or you have to set the constrainst to `CASCADE` if it is *MySQL*

Comment: I want a sql query that will delete all tables that has subscription or subsription_id. Its time consuming to select all the tables 1 at a time.

Comment: @jarlh Im not an expert. thats why I post a question here so that somebody can share there knowledge to me.. and by the way is that the best option to write 85 delete staments?

Comment: @John **Delete** the tables (remove the structure and data) or **truncate** them (delete only data)? That's a *big* difference!

Comment: @rbr94, `DROP` the tables to have them removed, or `DELETE`/`TRUNCATE`  to empty them.

Comment: @rbr94 only the data sir inside the subscription or subscription_id column

Comment: @John I provided a sample approach. Could I help you?

Comment: @rbr94 Yes, of course sir you can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the `TRUNCATE` statements for tables which have a `subscription_id` or `subscription` column:

```
SELECT DISTINCT concat( "TRUNCATE TABLE ", TABLE_NAME, ";" )
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('subscription_id','subscription')
        AND TABLE_SCHEMA='YourDatabase';
```

**EDIT 1:**

As mentioned in the comments, there is a need to disable to constraints in order to be able to truncate the tables in a random order with the query given above.

Sample disabling the constraints:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;

--Truncate statements execution

SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Comment: The OP will need to either disable constraints or re-order the statements generated as per Jens comment above.